# Quelle est la différence entre "en désarroi" et "au désarroi" ?

Tags: grammaire

Je me suis fatigué à chercher la différence entre "en désarroi" et "au désarroi" mais je n’ai rien trouvé.

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur FSE. Merci de détailler un peu la question et d'expliquer ce que tu as cherché et comment tu comprends cette expression, afin que l'on puisse t'aider de la meilleure des manières. :)

Comment: **En** désarroi. https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sarroi

Comment: "Au désarroi" se dit aussi. Je trouve que moinssage de cette question est sévère.

Answer (score 3):

***Désarroi*** emporte l'idée de **désordre** à la base, et au sens figuré quand il s'agit de personne, de trouble, d'inquiétude, d'angoisse voire de panique (voir [l'article du CRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sarroi) pointé par Toto). Comme si l'âme était en désordre.

**En désarroi** est donc synonyme de "en désordre", ou "troublé", ou "en panique", etc. quand il s'agit d'une personne.

Le "au" de l'expression **"au désarroi"** est la contraction de "à"+"le". "À" indique une destination. Le sens à donner dépend de la phrase.

> - Face au désarroi des foules, le maire resta muet
> - Les routes sont bloquées depuis le début de l'hiver, au désarroi des habitants du village

Dans la première phrase, c'est "face à" contracté avec "le désarroi". Le sens de l'expression s'obient avec celui de "face à" et celui de "le désarroi".

Dans la seconde phrase, on comprend que le blocage des routes a pour "destination" ou effet de provoquer le désarroi des habitants du village.